# wp acf custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

if the user is registered as an author, in my case the employer,
and has the ability to post job ads from the front end. Can I add another input field in post job ads form, and when he click submit button save that into posts custom field without any write from admin dashboard(backend) and how?

With my code when I post job ads from frontend it save all form but dont save my custom field with name

```
name="et_user_adress"
```

### Here is my form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label title-plan" for="mjesto-rada"><?php _e('Mjesto rada', ET_DOMAIN) ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="input-item form-control text-field" id="et_user_adress" name="et_user_adress" placeholder="Unesite naziv grada ili naselja" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit-login-form"><?php _e("Submit", ET_DOMAIN); ?></button>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I use ACF (advance custom fields plugin) and it work great when I make input from backend, but I need to to let customers to make input from frontend and save that to db and custom field.

### Here is code to show on frontend when I have input filled in backend

```
<li>
    <span class="text-normal">Mjesto rada </span> <span class="number-blue"><?php the_field('et_user_adress'); ?></span>

</li>
```

Comment: So you'd like the user (employer) to be able to post to the database, but from the frontend rather than the backend? I think I'm misunderstanding so I wanna check before I answer anything :)

Comment: Yes user (employer) don't have access to backend.

Comment: Please show your code, where you are submitting the form?

Comment: Would this help in any way? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/

Comment: Did you get this sorted @PrateekVerma?